# How to display text only from target php script

Tags: php

I have an assigment to put 100 random characters into array in **main.php** and send it to **output.php**. And in the **output.php** I have to output just those 100 characters in table. I've done this like this, but it outputs the '**main.php**' and '**output.php**'
 **main.php:**

```
   <?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    $charstring[$i]=chr(rand(33,125));
foreach($charstring as $c){
    echo $c;
}
<br><br> <a href='output.php'>Send</a>
?>
```

**output.php:**

```
<?php
require 'main.php';
echo "<table style='border-collapse:collapse;'>";
$i=0;
foreach($charstring as $c){
    if($i%10==0){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>".$c."</td>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</tr></table>;"
?>
<br><br><a style='text-decoration:none;'; href='main.php'>Back</a>
```

Comment: If you `echo` something in a file, then that is where it will be outputted. Btw, I see no reference to any file called `second.php` in your code?

Comment: Sorry it should be 'output.php'

Comment: You're currently not "sending" the data to output.php, you're including the main into output (basically concatenating the files). If you need to "send" them, you probably need to post them in a form/use ajax or add them as a querystring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending anything from your first file to your second file.

If I understand it correctly, you want to send the 100 characters that you generate in your first script to the second script when you click the link.

To do that, you could - for example - add them to the link and read the value in `output.php` instead of running the same code again by including it, generating a new string in the process.

This example would look like:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    $charstring[$i]=chr(rand(33,125));
foreach($charstring as $c){
    echo $c;
}
// Generate a string from the array and encode it to use it in a query string
?>
<br><br> <a href='output.php?string=<?php echo urlencode(implode('', $charstring)); ?>'>Send</a>
```

And in `output.php`:

```
...
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['string']);
...
```

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks, I was just in the process of correcting that :-)

Comment: He would also need to explode the string to be able to show it in a table, but since it's an "assignment ", I don't think we should do _all_ his homework for him. :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson True :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Although you can interpret "putting in a table" pretty broadly ;-)

Comment: So, if I got this right. With function urlencode() I send variable $charstring to output.php
and then with htmlspecialchars() I read it and output it?